# Are there instances of 'i' meaning 'and' in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía, conjunciones, dialectos

I know 'y' and sometimes 'e' but is 'i' ever used and in what cases or countries? Is that conflation with Portuguese?

Comment: No.  But it is used in Catalan and Mirandese.  Portuguese uses *e* always.

Comment: Thanks; that's pretty much what I thought and confirms pretty much my SusPicions About the people e-Mailing.

Comment: However, I find some references in old books that may suggest that it was used instead of _y_ in Old Spanish.

Comment: fedorqui: it would have been quite rare, though. Although *⁊* was the preferred form throughout the 15th and 16th century, when otherwise written out, it was fairly universally either *e* (15th century) or *y* (16th).  The use of *i* would be a fairly extreme outlier, because one would actually expect *j* (the letters *i* and *j* still hadn't fully split their function yet)

Comment: Andrés Bello proposed a spelling reform which actually had some effect in South American countries. Some others proposed revised spellings independently, e.g. Manuel González Prada in _Pájinas libres_. However, during 20th those attempts were abandoned in favor of what RAE/ASALE dictates. That's a relative new event, though

Answer (score 3):

"i" is not correctly used in Spanish as "and" in any case. The only variation of "y" is using "e", when the following word starts with "i".